# Can I use Knime to write to a Microsoft Access database?

Tags: ms-access, knime

I'm trying to get Knime setup to export data into Access but I'm having trouble figuring out what node(s) to use and configuring them. I'm starting to wonder if it can write to Access or only read from it. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to add driver for Microsoft Access database cause dedicated [Microsoft Access Connector](https://kni.me/n/gYdNFHIzos2alqQ7) node is available from KNIME version 4.0. After successful connection you should be able to both read data from and write data to it. Check [this](https://kni.me/w/pWWGOClc1NJ9PIek) workflow for example.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can use [UCanAccess](http://ucanaccess.sourceforge.net/site.html) JDBC driver for writing to a lot of Access database types. You need to register it -and its dependencies- here (`File` | `Preferences` | `KNIME` | `Databases` | `Add`):

[image: File/Preferences/KNIME/Databases/Add]

You need to change the `Database type` from `default` to `msaccess` and add the required files/directory.

After that, you can use the [`DB` nodes](https://nodepit.com/category/db) to read/write Access dbs.